# Async command is not running

Tags: javascript

not sure why I don't get a console.log here

```
const inMemoryDb = newDb();

// eslint-disable-next-line no-return-await
const backup = (async () => await migrate())();

async function migrate() {
  console.log('entering migrate');

  await inMemoryDb.public.migrate();
  console.log('migrate called');

  const skills = inMemoryDb.public.many("select * from skills where name = 'Swift'");
  console.log('skills', skills);

  const backup = inMemoryDb.backup();
  return backup;
}

export { inMemoryDb, backup };
```

when I consume this singleton, I get a console.log for `console.log('entering migrate');` but not the second or third console.log

Comment: What is `newDb`? It seems like `migrate()` is never resolving.

Comment: is inMemoryDb.public.migrate(); throwing any errors

Comment: yea migrate() isn't resolving but it's not throwing errors either

Comment: @PositiveGuy Then please post its code so that we can help you solving that issue.

Comment: What's the point of `(async () => await migrate())()`? Why don't you write `const backup = migrate()`? Do you really want a promise that fulfills with `undefined` there?

Comment: @Bergi It does not resolve into `undefined`. The arrow function returns the result of `await migrate()`, since there are no braces present. However I agree that the whole construct seems pointless.

Comment: `// eslint-disable-next-line no-return-await` should be a red flag for you. `return await` is an anti-pattern. using an `async` function automatically returns a promise. it is exactly the same as writing `backup = (async () => await migrate())()` is the exact same as `backup = (() => migrate())()` which is exactly the same as `backup = migrate()`. don't make things so hard on yourself :D

Comment: Nothing is happening because you didn't `await backup` or `backup.then(console.log, console.error)`

Comment: @3limin4t0r Oh right I had expected to see braces because otherwise it made even less sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the code for it I'm making a guess, but as Bergi correctly pointed out, if execution stops at `inMemoryDb.public.migrate`, it likely is not resolving or rejecting the Promise. Here's a guess what that might look like:

```js
function newDb() {
  return {
    public: {
      migrate: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // does migration stuff
        });
      },
    },
  };
}
```

and how you *might* fix it:

```js
function newDb() {
  return {
    public: {
      migrate: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            // does migration stuff
            resolve();  // <-- important!
          }
          catch (error) {
            reject();   // <-- important!
          }
        });
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: yea the crap migrate() code was eating errors I think or something. But it didn't report a damn thing back for some reason